# Comparing two list C#

Tags: c#, lambda

I have entity which is as follows

```
public class A
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string AccountName { get; set; }
    public virtual string AccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Service> Services { get; set; }
}
```

I have another list which is of type Services which i want to compare with entity A.Services and get only those results of A which are matching (the same).

I want a lambda express or some way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement [**`IEquatable<Service>`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) and then you can use [**`Intersect`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) as below

```
var common = services1.Intersect(services2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have you class implement IEquatable, and then use Linq Intersect.

```
public class A : IEquatable<A>
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string AccountName { get; set; }
    public virtual string AccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Service> Services { get; set; }

    //Implement IEquatable interfaces 
    //...
}
```

Note that when using LINQ Intersection call, use below one:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Intersect<TSource>(
          this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
          IEnumerable<TSource> second,
          IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer) //  <--- This is important
```

Comment: Thanks david but I am new in using this type of stuff IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer) . If possible please give a sample code snipped.

Comment: @user1394622, you may have a look at http://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2009/11/26/ling-operation-union-intersect-except-and-iequatablet/, to see an example how to tell if two points are the same. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Enumerable.Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) method.

> Produces the set intersection of two sequences by using the default
>   equality comparer to compare values.

```
public class A : IEquatable<Service>
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string AccountName { get; set; }
    public virtual string AccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Service> Services { get; set; }
}

var commonListofService = services1.Intersect(services2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have a method on class A that does it, then you don't need to bother with IEquatable...

```
public class A
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string AccountName { get; set; }
    public virtual string AccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Service> Services { get; set; }

    public List<Service> GetCommonServices(A compareTo)
    {
         return this.Services.Intersect(compareTo.Services);
    }
}
```